# In flutter_quill how to make BlockEmbed only take the required width instead of the full width of the editor

Tags: flutter, quill

In flutter_quill (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#custom-embed-blocks) how to make BlockEmbed (TextButton in the following example) only take the required width instead of the full width of the editor? Wrapping the TextButton with Container or SizedBox did not yield the required result.

```
class CallbackAnchorEmbedBuilder extends EmbedBuilder {
  /// CallbackAnchor builder implements an embeddable anchor block,
  /// which when tapped (when the editor is in read-only mode), calls the [onAnchorTap] function.
  CallbackAnchorEmbedBuilder({this.addEditAnchor, this.onTapAnchor});

  Future<void> Function(BuildContext context, {Document? document})?
      addEditAnchor;
  bool Function(String value)? onTapAnchor;

  @override
  String get key => callbackAnchorNoteType;

  @override
  String toPlainText(Embed node) {
    return node.value.data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    QuillController controller,
    Embed node,
    bool readOnly,
    bool inline,
    TextStyle textStyle,
  ) {
    final anchorTag = CallbackAnchorBlockEmbed(node.value.data).document;
    return SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (readOnly) {
            if (onTapAnchor != null) {
              onTapAnchor!(anchorTag.toDelta().first.attributes?['id']);
            }
          } else {
            addEditAnchor!(context, document: anchorTag);
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          anchorTag.toPlainText().replaceAll('\n', ' '),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: textStyle.copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```